# 80's Post apocalyptic novel with psychic centaurs and organic airships

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic

Does this ring any bells? The airships were plant forms that floated and could be used for transportation. There was a diverse cast of characters on some quest, including some sort of psychic centaur-like creature.

Answer (score 15):

This sounds like John Varley's [Gaean Trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaea_trilogy) ([Titan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_%28John_Varley_novel%29), [Wizard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizard_%28novel%29), [Demon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_%28novel%29))

[image] [image] [image]

It has the living airships:

> “That’s our way off this cliff,” he said. “His name is—” he pursed his
>   lips and whis­tled three clear notes with a war­ble at the end, “—but
>   I see that’s awk­ward to use mixed with Eng­lish. I call him
>   Whistlestop.”
>
> “You call him ‘Whistlestop,’” Cirocco re­peated, numbly.
>
> “That’s right. He’s a blimp.”
>
> “A blimp.”
>
> He looked at her oddly and she grit­ted her teeth. “He looks more like
>   a di­ri­gi­ble, but he’s not, be­cause he doesn’t have a rigid
>   skele­ton. I’ll call him and you can see for your­self.” He put two
>   fin­gers to his lips and whis­tled a long, com­plex tune with odd
>   mu­si­cal in­ter­vals.

And the centaurs:

> The Ti­tanide found them while they were tak­ing down the tent prior
>   to mov­ing Bill. It stood on the top of the bluff where Cirocco had
>   been the day be­fore. Cirocco waited for it to make the first move,
>   but it seemed to have the same idea.
>
> The most ob­vi­ous word for the thing was cen­taur. It had a lower
>   part shaped like a horse, and an upper half so human it was
>   fright­en­ing. Cirocco was not quite sure she be­lieved in it.
>
> It was not as Dis­ney had en­vi­sioned cen­taurs, nor did it have much
>   to do with the clas­si­cal Greek model. It had a lot of hair, yet its
>   dom­i­nant fea­ture was pale naked skin. There were great
>   multi-col­ored cas­cades of hair on the head and tail, on the lower
>   parts of all four legs, and on the crea­ture’s fore­arms. Odd­est of
>   all, there was hair be­tween the two front legs, in the place where a
>   de­cent horse—which Cirocco’s mind kept try­ing to see—had noth­ing
>   but smooth hide. It car­ried a shep­herd’s crook, and but for a few
>   small or­na­ments, wore no cloth­ing.

The Blimps and Centaurs "speak" a very music-based language, but it's hinted that it may have a telepathic component.

The first book, Titan, is a fairly straightforward adventure story. The second book, Wizard is more of a "quest" type of story. The last book, Demon is a post-apocalypse/revolution/war story with a little social commentary thrown in. From the OP's question it sounds like they may only have read the second book. Although the third book has more of the post-apocalytic events, it also has a... *larger-than-life* character that would be pretty hard to forget.

Comment: This series is one of my favorites to reread, so even if it is not the book you seek, you might still want to read it.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is [Dark is the Sun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Is_the_Sun), by Philip Jose Farmer.  It's set in the very far future, the characters travel in/on a giant plant pod for part of their adventures, and one of the characters is a plant-centaur shaman with psychic powers.  The group of main characters were trying to recover their stolen 'Soul Eggs'.

[image]

Comment: Were there also  centaurs in the Farmer Riverworld novels?

Comment: @DWin: No. Everyone in Farmer's *Riverworld* series is human or at least humanoid.

Comment: See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160169/post-apocalyptic-novel-one-character-a-centaur-with-a-mouth-in-the-middle-of-it for a newer question that suggests this is the correct answer.