# Looking for a book titled 'The Wizard'

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a book titled *The Wizard*. It is about a guy who traveled with this Wizard in this land of centaur like beings that were hermaphrodites. The wizard had to fertilize the eggs of the centaurs by putting them in her mouth. Does this sound familiar at all? There was this space elevator that took people from earth to I want to say to a ship that took them to paradise....????

Comment: I'm confused. You know the title, so what are you looking for?

Comment: @phantom42 I didn't notice that he mentioned the title.  This is a strange question indeed.  Robert, are you asking where you can buy the book?  If so, you should probably try Amazon, not SE.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68423/80s-post-apocalyptic-novel-with-psychic-centaurs-and-organic-airships

Answer (score 13):

I think you are looking for [The Gaea Trilogy by John Varley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaea_trilogy).

- In book one, [*Titan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(John_Varley_novel)), we are introduced to the Titanides, a centaur-like race.
- In book two, [*Wizard*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizard_(novel)), "the Titanides [are] dependent on Cirocco Jones to have children. Only her saliva can activate the eggs they produce, so that they can be implanted in a host mother to grow".
- Book 3 is called *Demon*.

I believe there may be a space elevator.

Comment: How the hell did you beat me to it?  Damn it.  Good answer, by the way. +1

Comment: I'm in the Google zone tonight.